# passing sqlite3_stmt in objective c

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

I have a problem in objective-c. I am triying to create a common database access in my app by handling the opening, consult and closing of the database in one class, and then processing the sqlite3_stmt variable in another class, but when I try to return the sqlite3_stmt variable I get the error "incompatible types in return". (and they are both sqlite3_stmt, i have checked.) here is the code, as simplified as I can. Any help would be greatly appreciated:

HEADER:

```
@interface statement : NSObject
{
sqlite3_stmt *consulta;
}

-(void)setConsulta:(sqlite3_stmt *)c;

-(sqlite3_stmt)getConsulta;

@end
```

BODY

```
import "statement.h"


@implementation statement

//@synthesize consulta;

-(void)setConsulta:(sqlite3_stmt *)c

{
    self.consulta=c;
}

-(sqlite3_stmt)getConsulta

{
    return consulta;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

In "-(sqlite3_stmt)getConsulta" you're missing a *. It should be

```
-(sqlite3_stmt *)getConsulta { .... }
```

Don't forget to fix it in the @implementation as well.